# Possible to embed markdown within erb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, haml, erb

If you use haml as rails view template, you can write portion of your page using markdown by using the ":markdown" filter.

Is is possible to do the same using erb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ERB does not have filtering like this built-in. You'll need to directly use a gem that handles it, like RDiscount or the venerable BlueCloth.

Comment: To be fair, Haml doesn't have Markdown support built-in either: it uses whatever Markdown gems are available on the system.

Also, I would recommend the pure-Ruby Maruku library over the C-based RDiscount and BlueCloth, unless speed is a serious issue (which it shouldn't be with good caching).

Answer (score 9):

It's pretty easy to write a method that does it, assuming you're using something like Rails which has `#capture`, `#concat`, and `#markdown` helpers. Here's an example, using Maruku:

```
def markdown_filter(&block)
  concat(markdown(capture(&block)))
end
```

Then you can use this as so:

```
<% markdown_filter do %>
# Title

This is a *paragraph*.

This is **another paragraph**.
<% end %>
```

There are a few things to note here. First, it's important that all the text in the block have no indentation; you could get around this by figuring out the common indentation of the lines and removing it, but I didn't do that in the example helper above. Second, it uses Rails' `#markdown` helper, which could easily be implemented in other frameworks as so (replacing `Maruku` with your Markdown processor of choice):

```
def markdown(text)
  Maruku.new(text).to_html
end
```

Rails 3 has removed the `#markdown` helper, so just add the above code in the appropriate helper, substituting the Markdown processor of your choice.